# pulp.pulpTestAll() :has no attribute 'pulpTestAll'

Tags: import, package, installation, pulp, glpk

I just installed pulp and followed instructions here: https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/main/installing_pulp_at_home.html#testing-your-pulp-installation

however it shows the following message:

```
AttributeError: module 'pulp' has no attribute 'pulpTestAll'
```

besides that, the glpk can't be installed either:

```
(base) MBP:pulp-1.4.0 ci$ sudo apt-get install glpk
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

can anyone help? thanks

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue today. It seems the test functionality has been removed in PuLP 2.0.

This is described here:
https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/issues/253

Can't help you with the GLPK install I'm afraid, been a while since I worked in Linux, but that seems unrelated to PuLP, as that is only the LP-interface.

It has been the case for a while that for PuLP to detect your solvers on linux you needed to run the test, so maybe you can try following the tip in the github discussion, regarding downloading the help functionality from the github code. Then you can run the test and PuLP can detect the solvers on your system after you've installed them.

Answer (score 2):

For installing glpk, go to the link below

https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-sudo-apt-get-command-not-found-on-macos/

Follow the section titled as "Method 1: Installing Homebrew in macOS" in the middle of the page.

Once done, run the command below

brew install glpk

It worked for me. Hope it works for you too.